# Can i use a slower clock rate for a CPU or a Microcontroller than the one it is supposed to use?

Tags: microcontroller, cpu, clock-speed

Say i have a CPU or a Microcontroller with a clock rate of 1 GHz, can i use a 1 kHz instead?

Comment: 1 GHz processors do not have simple clocking - that part of your question is clearly made up without reference to details of any real device.   In the more common case of easy-to-work-with microcontrollers, moderns designs are almost always "fully static" meaning that they can function at arbitrarily low clock rates.

Comment: TFM will specify minimum and maximum clock speed. When you go outside the specified limits, you "under-/overclock", which means that the manufacturer makes no guarantees that it will work. This is why "factory overclocking" is a BS marketing term.

Answer (score 3):

Read the data sheet. Processors that have a minimum clock frequency will say so.

Comment: I would expect a minimum slew rate on the clock edges because of cross conduction, but excluding dynamic designs, why would the clock have a minimum frequency? Can you provide an example or an explanation? Genuinely asking a question here.

Comment: @VladimirCravero As one example some CPUs/MCUs have integrated PLLs which won't lock if the frequency is too low.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: Not all processors use static logic internally. Dynamic logic can save a lot of power and complexity, but loses its mind if clocked too slowly.

Comment: The PLL thing intrigues me a bit. It might be because I have only studied ideal models, so I can't really see where they can fail. I guess VCOs have a minimum output frequency, or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing which microcontroller you are using, most likely yes. The main clock can often be divided by a number of options to run at less than maximum speed. And any sub clocks as well.